# How to add a rating to a value in python

Tags: python

19/3/22

I am trying to add a rating of severity to an air_quality index.

Ive tried:

```
def determine_score(aqi):
   if aqi >= 0 and aqi <= 50:
      return "Normal"
   elif aqi >= 51 and aqi <= 100:
      return "Mild"
   elif aqi >= 101 and aqi <= 150:
      return "Moderate"
   elif aqi >= 151 and aqi <= 250:
      return "Some Unhealthy"
   else:
      return " All unhealthy"

   lbl2.config("<return>", determine_score)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Kindly provide more details like *what do you mean by rating to a value, what error/problem you are facing.*

Answer (score 0):

So, the function of `lbl2` is unclear. But the calling of the function is not proper. the function requires an argument. So call it using

```
determine_score(aqi) # aqi is the value of the aqi you want to check
```

Since the commands kinda seem like tkinter, if they are you need to use lambda functions. Though I am not very familiar with tkinter.

```
lbl2.config("", lambda: determine_score(input_from_user))
```

Reference:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tkinter-button-commands-with-lambda-in-python